# Verify API Response

Tags: rest, restsharp

Am getting the response of a request like this:
var response = command.PostCommand(testCommand);

I will like to validate that the response is in a json format so am doing it like this:

Assert.AreEqual("application/json", response.ContentType);

Is this way correctly or do i need to specifically validate it from the content-type header response?

Comment: No this not a correct way to identify just based on header. you should use json parser to actually validate that the response is in JSON format

Comment: @NullPointerException can you provide an example? please

Comment: https://airbrake.io/blog/javascript-error-handling/syntaxerror-json-parse-bad-parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IRestRequest.OnBeforeDeserialization` callback to check the response content type before it gets deserialised:

```
var request = new RestRequest(url)
    .AddQueryParameter(x, y); // whatever you need to configure

request.OnBeforeDeserialization = 
    response => CheckContentType(response.ContentType);

await client.PostAsync<MyResponse>(request);
```

Comment: Am using Restsharp for making the request and Nunit for the assertions